# Allow unused named arguments in Rust's format!() family

Tags: rust

Given:

```
format!("{red}{}{reset}", "text", red = "RED", blue = "BLUE", reset = "RESET");
```

The compilers exits with an error:

```
error: named argument never used
  --> example.rs:1:47
   |
 1 |         format!("{red}{}{reset}", "text", red = "RED", blue = "BLUE", reset = "RESET");
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Normally, this wouldn't be a problem as `blue` should be removed, but my usecase is a wrapper macro (simplified):

```
macro_rules! log {
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => {
        println!($fmt, $($arg)*, blue = "BLUE", red = "RED", reset = "RESET");
    };
}
```

Sometimes, it is used like this (simplified), but other times with different colours, you get the gist:

```
log!("{red}{}{reset}", "text");
```

The compiler exits with an analogous error:

```
error: named argument never used
  --> example.rs:3:26
   |
3  |         println!($fmt, $($arg)*, blue = "BLUE", red = "RED", reset = "RESET");
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is it possible to just *ignore* the unused arguments, instead of erroring on them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the set of colors are all known, you could "consume" them with zero-length arguments:

```
macro_rules! log {
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => {
        println!(concat!($fmt, "{blue:.0}{red:.0}{reset:.0}"),  // <--
                 $($arg)*,
                 blue="BLUE", 
                 red="RED", 
                 reset="RESET")
    }
}

fn main() {
    log!("{red}{}{reset}", "<!>");
    // prints: RED<!>RESET
}
```

([Docs for `concat!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat.html))

Note that the strings `BLUE`, `RED`, `RESET` will still be sent to the formatting function, so it will incur a minor overhead even nothing will be printed.

---

I think this is quite error prone, since if you forget a `{reset}` the rest of your console will become red. I wonder why not write something like:

```
macro_rules! log_red {
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => {
        println!(concat!("RED", $fmt, "RESET"), $($arg)*);
    }
}
// also define `log_blue!`.

log_red!("{}", "text");
```

Comment: "Note that the strings BLUE, RED, RESET will still be sent", so if I use an instance of a thing that implements `Display`, will that still call `Display::fmt` on it? "forget a {reset} the rest " because I have multiple colours arbitrarily mixed per line, the simple strings are just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lead me to update the supporting library and learn some new things about Rust's `Display::fmt`

Comment: @набиячлэвэли: It must still call `Display::fmt`, the library is not yet smart enough to know `.0` is special (the `.N` stuff is handled in `Display::fmt` IIRC).

Comment: Yep, I figured that, so I specialcase on `f.precision() == Some(0)` in my implementation of `Display::fmt()` to prevent that.

Comment: Apparently, this trick does not work for `Debug` types, i.e. if `red=SomeNonDisplayType`. As a workaround: `format!(concat!($fmt, "{red:.0}"), args..., red=format!("{:?}", red))`