# How can I allow unused named arguments that do not implement Display in a call to format!?

Tags: rust, macros

In a macro, given an opaque format string and some variables, how do I format a string even if the format string does not reference all the variables?

For instance, given the string `"You are {age} years old"`, `age` and `birthday` :

- I cannot generate `format!("You are {age} years old", age=age, birthday=birthday)`, because I would get: `error: named argument never used`.
- I cannot generate `format!("You are {age} years old", age=age)`, because I have no way of knowing statically in the macro whether the format string references `birthday` or not.
- I cannot use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841400/allow-unused-named-arguments-in-rusts-format-family?answertab=active#tab-top) and generate `format!("You are {age} years old{age:.0}{birthday:.0}", age=age.to_string(), birthday=birthday.to_string())` because `birthday` is a variable of a type that does not implement `std::fmt::Display`.

I need this in order to add support for non-displayable parameters to my [custom-error](https://github.com/lovasoa/custom_error) crate.

This question is similar to [Allow unused named arguments in Rust's format!() family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841400/allow-unused-named-arguments-in-rusts-format-family), but is about non-displayable arguments.

Comment: Not quite getting the context here.. `format!` requires the format string to be static, which means a macro can determine the names in it. If you have values that are neither displayable nor used, why pass them to `format!`?

Comment: This is for a macro that is available as a library. The format string is known by the user of the library, but is opaque to the macro. The values are the fields in a struct, so there is no way for the macro to know which fields are used in the format string and which aren't.

Comment: I didn't want to make the question unreadable by adding a huge macro, but the exact place where it is needed is here: https://github.com/lovasoa/custom_error/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L383-L392

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but I think that you are solving the wrong problem. By doing the hardcoding this way, it appears that you will prevent being able to call methods on the error values, such as `Path::display`. SNAFU avoids this problem by [allowing the user to specify all the arguments to `write!` and allowing unused variables](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/blob/31ac98aa3b4aff990fc8c5f416489f485cebf8cb/snafu-derive/src/lib.rs#L1386-L1391). (I also recommend just *using* SNAFU instead of writing a new crate, but I'm biased there)

Comment: The sole goal of custom-error is to remove boilerplate. There are many other error libraries that help define error types, but all of them involve writing more code, and result in code that is in my opinion not as clear and readable. So I would really like being able to keep the simple syntax that is currently implemented.

Comment: custom-error doesn't prevent writing custom error formatting code, it is simply not the default:
 https://docs.rs/custom_error/1.7.0/custom_error/macro.custom_error.html#custom-formatting-function-for-error-messages

Comment: "How can I allow unused named arguments that do not implement Display in a call to format!?" no